# How can I put the head of an arrow lies on a side of a square with pin?

Tags: pgfplots

I used pin to put an arrow at lies on a side of a square, but I can't with one (S_2).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
    [
    declare function={Y(\x)=\x^3 -6 * \x^2+9*\x;},
axis line style = very thick,
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-0.5:5,
        ymin=-0.5,
        ymax=4.5,
        xmin=-1.2,
        xmax=4.95,
        ytick={4},
    samples=100,xtick distance=1,ytick distance=1
,unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    width=11cm,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!30}]
\addplot [black,  thick,name path =A] {Y(x)};
       \addplot [black, mark=*,only marks,samples at={0,1,3,4}] {Y(x)};
       \node at (axis cs:-0.25, -0.25) {$O$} ;
       \addplot [ thick] coordinates {(4, 0) (4, 4) (0,4)};
\addplot[name path =C,domain=0:4] {4};
\addplot[name path =D,domain=0:4] {0};
\addplot[pattern=north east lines,  domain=0:1,samples=1000] fill between[of=A and D,soft clip={domain=3:4},];
\addplot[pattern=north east lines,  domain=0:1,samples=1000] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=0:1},];
\begin{scope}[
  every pin edge/.style={thick,<-,>=latex},
  pin distance=1.5cm
]
\node[pin=60:{$S_2$},] at (axis cs:4.001,1.3) {};
\node[pin=-150:{$S_1$},] at (axis cs:0.1,2) {};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I correct them?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to achieve. Would `\node[pin=60:{$S_2$},] at (axis cs:4.001,2) {};` do what you want?

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, that you like to achieve something like this:

[image]

For this you need to make node `inner sep=0`, or use the following equivalent solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    declare function={Y(\x)=\x^3 -6 * \x^2+9*\x;},
axis line style = very thick,
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-0.5:5,
        ymin=-0.5,
        ymax=4.5,
        xmin=-1.2,
        xmax=4.95,
        ytick={4},
    samples=100,xtick distance=1,ytick distance=1
,unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    width=11cm,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!30}]
\addplot [black,  thick,name path =A] {Y(x)};
       \addplot [black, mark=*,only marks,samples at={0,1,3,4}] {Y(x)};
       \node at (axis cs:-0.25, -0.25) {$O$} ;
       \addplot [ thick] coordinates {(4, 0) (4, 4) (0,4)};
\addplot[name path =C,domain=0:4] {4};
\addplot[name path =D,domain=0:4] {0};
\addplot[pattern=north east lines,  domain=0:1,samples=1000] fill between[of=A and D,soft clip={domain=3:4},];
\addplot[pattern=north east lines,  domain=0:1,samples=1000] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=0:1},];
\begin{scope}[
  every pin edge/.style={thick,latex-},
  pin distance=1.5cm
]
\node[coordinate,pin=  60:{$S_2$}] at (axis cs:4,1.3) {};
\node[coordinate,pin=-150:{$S_1$}] at (axis cs:0,2) {};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Note:*
please consider to upgrade your `pgfplots` to recent version (1.14), whic enable more simple set coordinates. For example, for nodes with `pin`:

```
\node[coordinate,pin=  60:{$S_2$}] at (4,1.3) {};
\node[coordinate,pin=-150:{$S_1$}] at (0,2) {};
```

Comment: How can I upgrade my pgfplots?

Comment: depends of which LaTeX installation you have. With MikTeX (which I use)  is update utility and update utility (Admin), by which you can upgrade your whole installation (recommended) or specifically only one package (from all offered you select only `pgfplots`.